# How to draw square in Assembly language?

Tags: assembly

I want to draw a square in Assembly language. I have ridden something about `int 10h`. Does anybody know, how to do it? Please place here some piece of code to tell what can I use for drawing a square, or some quality tutorials. Thanks.

Comment: `int 10h` is a video BIOS interrupt that is older than dirt and cannot be accessed from user mode in current operating systems. Are you running MS-DOS?

Comment: Do you mean from DOS (emulation)? If so, what video mode are you working in? Otherwise, what graphics API do you want to target?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Like Frederic Hamidi said, "int 0x10h" is an obsolete BIOS interface.  If you're interested in assembly, I would strongly encourage to AVOID 16-bit, DOS/Masm tutorials and learn on a more modern OS (like Linux).

I'd highly recommend "Programming from the Ground Up", by Jonathan Bartlett:

http://savannah.nongnu.org/projects/pgubook/

Nevertheless, if you REALLY want to draw a line (or a square) in 16-bit real mode (i.e. in DOS), here's an example:

http://lateblt.tripod.com/asm.htm

```
; Draw a line in a graphics mode

;By extension, draws a yellow line in the upper-left.
;A good example of how to efficiently use INC, CMP,
;and a conditional jump for repetitive tasks.

mov ah,00h
mov al,13h
int 10h

;The above three lines just switch to 320x200 256-color VGA.

mov ds,40960
;a000h = 40960 decimal
mov ax, 44h
;44h is yellow! ;)
mov bx,0000
START:
mov [bx],ax
inc bx
cmp bx,20
JL START

;This waits until BX reaches 20, then exits!

mov ah,004C  ;terminate program
int 21h
```

Comment: Thank you very much! And I want to ask, how can I draw more lines underneath?

Comment: As you can see, the above code puts the PC into 320x200x8 mode (int 0x0x10, mode 0x13), then draws 20 yellow pixels (0x44) to the video buffer (address 40960 == 0xa000).  The video buffer is actually an array.  The first pixel in the first row is 0xa000 + 0, the second pixel in the first row is 0xa000 + 1, etc.  The first pixel in the second row is 0xa000 + 200, the second is 0xa000 + 201, etc.  If you want to draw any pixel in any row, just compute the offset.  To draw a horizontal line, just add "1".  To draw a vertical line, just add "200".  Make sense?

Comment: Please correct me if I'm wrong. So i must fill first line to fill the second? But thank you very much, I think I need that what i needed.

Comment: That's hardly a good example.  You're doing 2-byte stores (of AX, not AL) but only incrementing the pointer by 1.  So the last iteration stores a `0` byte to `[20]`, the 21st byte.

Comment: Other than what @PeterCordes said: `mov ds,40960` is an invalid instruction (not encodable) and `mov ah,004C` is confusing with those 2 leading zeroes. What would make sense is `mov AX, 4C00h`.

Answer (score 4):

The only possible reason I can think of for doing something like this is to gain experience in the ways in which primitive shapes are rasterized.  As commenters have pointed out, you really can't do this kind of thing in your CPU's assembly language much anymore, if at all.  Modern computers have graphics cards. Perhaps you want to learn how to talk to those device drivers?  Or maybe you could hit a semi-portable API like Windows GDI.  There are just too many variables in this question.

Just for fun, here is a flippant answer.  You can access the OpenGL API from an assembly language program.  Years ago (2002 to be precise), I had a Windows machine and wrote a NASM program to draw the colored triangle that was in the beginning of the famous red book.  You might be able to tweak it to draw a square.  Here it is:

```
; ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
; triangle.asm
;
; A very simple *Windows* OpenGL application using the GLUT library.  It
; draws a nicely colored triangle in a top-level application window.  One
; interesting thing is that the Windows GL and GLUT functions do NOT use the
; C calling convention; instead they use the "stdcall" convention which is
; like C except that the callee pops the parameters.
; ----------------------------------------------------------------------------

        global  _main
        extern  _glClear@4
        extern  _glBegin@4
        extern  _glEnd@0
        extern  _glColor3f@12
        extern  _glVertex3f@12
        extern  _glFlush@0
        extern  _glutInit@8
        extern  _glutInitDisplayMode@4
        extern  _glutInitWindowPosition@8
        extern  _glutInitWindowSize@8
        extern  _glutCreateWindow@4
        extern  _glutDisplayFunc@4
        extern  _glutMainLoop@0

        section .text
title:  db      'A Simple Triangle', 0
zero:   dd      0.0
one:    dd      1.0
half:   dd      0.5
neghalf:dd      -0.5

display:
        push    dword 16384
        call    _glClear@4              ; glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT)
        push    dword 9
        call    _glBegin@4              ; glBegin(GL_POLYGON)
        push    dword 0
        push    dword 0
        push    dword [one]
        call    _glColor3f@12           ; glColor3f(1, 0, 0)
        push    dword 0
        push    dword [neghalf]
        push    dword [neghalf]
        call    _glVertex3f@12          ; glVertex(-.5, -.5, 0)
        push    dword 0
        push    dword [one]
        push    dword 0
        call    _glColor3f@12           ; glColor3f(0, 1, 0)
        push    dword 0
        push    dword [neghalf]
        push    dword [half]
        call    _glVertex3f@12          ; glVertex(.5, -.5, 0)
        push    dword [one]
        push    dword 0
        push    dword 0
        call    _glColor3f@12           ; glColor3f(0, 0, 1)
        push    dword 0
        push    dword [half]
        push    dword 0
        call    _glVertex3f@12          ; glVertex(0, .5, 0)
        call    _glEnd@0                ; glEnd()
        call    _glFlush@0              ; glFlush()
        ret

_main:
        push    dword [esp+8]           ; push argv
        lea     eax, [esp+8]            ; get addr of argc (offset changed :-)
        push    eax
        call    _glutInit@8             ; glutInit(&argc, argv)
        push    dword 0
        call    _glutInitDisplayMode@4
        push    dword 80
        push    dword 80
        call    _glutInitWindowPosition@8
        push    dword 300
        push    dword 400
        call    _glutInitWindowSize@8
        push    title
        call    _glutCreateWindow@4
        push    display
        call    _glutDisplayFunc@4
        call    _glutMainLoop@0
        ret
```

Now this program works only on Windows and you need to have OpenGL and GLUT on your machine.

If you need to tweak it for Linux (or the Mac or Solaris or whatever) you need to figure out how all the OpenGL calls work; they almost assuredly won't have the same names as in this Windows API I used.

I wouldn't bother with it, really.  Its only value is to illustrate assembly language calls, really.